# Javascript function returns null when running extension, but Boolean when using console

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, callback

I am trying to write an executeScript function. My problem is that when i run
`Boolean($(".sold-out-title")[0])'` in console, I get a Boolean value, but in my function the only thing being returned to my callback is null. I've been trying to figure this out for awhile now and can't seem to get anywhere. Any thoughts?

Background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse, ) {
    if (request.message === "open_new_tab") {
      // open the new tab up
      chrome.tabs.create({
          url: request.url,
          active: true
        });
      var soldOutStatus;
      chrome.tabs.executeScript({code: 'Boolean($(".sold-out-title")[0])'}, function(err, result){
        console.log(err)
        console.log(result);
        if(result == false){
            alert('Not sold out.')
        } else{
            alert('Sold out!')
        };
      });
```

Comment: Stop using jQuery for trivial things or inject it before using it. Your content script runs in a different context, which doesn't have page scripts, you can see by switching it in console toolbar ("top" is the default page context).

Answer (score 0):

Your `$(".sold-out-title")[0]` is returning a **string** of `null`, not a literal **[null object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null)**. Any string will return a `Boolean` of `true`. This can be seen below:

```js
console.log(Boolean(null)); // false
console.log(Boolean('null')); // true
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful! Although I still can't seem to get it to return a different value. It always seems to be returning true now, even when the class is undefined on the page.

Comment: Also, i just did typeof(result) and the result is an object, so I believe a null object is actually being returned.

Answer (score 0):

### You're using jQuery, which does not exist

Content scripts exist in a context/scope that is separate from the page. Thus, jQuery does not exist in that context unless you inject it. For running such a trivial amount of code, you should not inject jQuery, which is 85kiB of minimized code. You should not inject it just for the convenience of saving yourself a few characters of code (or even a few/several/many hundreds of characters). Doing so is just lazy programming.

In jQuery, the normal construct would be:

```
if($(".sold-out-title").length){}
```

If you *really* want an actual Boolean, then it would normally be

```
var myBoolean = !!$(".sold-out-title").length;
```

In vanilla JavaScript that would be:

```
var myBoolean = !!document.querySelectorAll(".sold-out-title").length;
```

However, because you are searching just for a class, not a more complex selector, you arguably should use [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) instead, as it's significantly faster. You don't need to, but it's just good practice . Like:

```
var myBoolean = !!document.getElementsByClassName("sold-out-title").length;
```

### Even if jQuery is injected, your code still won't work

For some reason you're callback function has two arguments:

```
function(err, result)
```

when the [documentation for the callback function](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#property-callback-result) states there is only one. Further, you are treating the `result` as a single result when the documentation states that you will receive an Array of results. If you are wanting to detect errors, which you should, errors are reported in [`chrome.runtime.lastError`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#property-lastError).

So, you code should look something like:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: '!!document.getElementsByClassName("sold-out-title").length'
}, function (results) {
    console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
    console.log(results[0]);
    if (results[0]) {
        alert('Not sold out.');
    } else {
        alert('Sold out!');
    }
});
```